Would it be possible to connect 2 routers to single PC?
I wish to connect device 4 (D4) to my LAN but I want to make sure it wont be able to connect to the internet.
I have spent two evenings on this problem and have zero progress.
Is it possible to make such network?

Router 1 - huawei HG8245X6-10
Router 2 - asus RT-AC51U
switch - Netgear GS105
If necessary I can buy some other stuff. ALso have RPi 3B+ on my disposal.
Obvious thing to do is to setup firewall for D4 on Router 1 but it doesn't have such capabilities. It has parental control but it cause D4 fail to obtain ip address, therefore its invisible to all other devices (i can see its MAC in the router 1).
Therefore I was wondering if i can use Router 2 which has much more configurability, but i cant get it to work the way i want.
No, placing router 2 right "beneath" router 1 will severely slow down my internet (10/100Mb ports, while router one gives me 800-900Mb download speeds), router 2 has much worse bandwidth.
Also I was wondering whenever swapping Router 2 with RPi 3 with some OpenWrt or some firewall app would solve my issues - cut out all packets from D4 that wants to leave my LAN.

”will severely slow down my internet, router 2 has much worse bandwidth.” - I hate submitting vague generic answers. So can you provide specifics?

Hey I have updated the description - router 1 gives me 800-900Mbit download speed, routner 2 has 10/100Mbit ports...

You are overthinking it.
You don't need extra equipment. You don't need the 2nd router.
Just configure the TCP IP settings in D4 manually (not by DHCP) and give it an non-existing ip-address as default gateway.
Without a working default gateway it will not be able to communicate outside the local LAN.

Huh, refreshing idea actually. Thank You. Unfortunately D4 is 3d printer that doesnt allow such modifications, at least not without flashing diffrent firmware which i want to avoid for the time being (its running custom klipper). All this problem arise from the fact that i dont trust fully this device.

@Iodrex A networked device that ONLY does DHCP? No manual configuration possible? That is beyond stupid. Please tell me the brand, so I can put it on my "never buy" list.
